# pcre(php) regular expression to match url

Tags: php, regex, url

I am working on SEO thing in project to match best URL from possible url's, so 
i am trying to match request url using `preg_match()` function from url pattern

can anyone please help me create regular expression to match only specific urls from all urls, i am newbie in Regular expression, please see my stuff

following **3** urls

> 1). http://domain.com/pressrelease/index/1
>   2). http://domain.com/pressrelease/123
>   3). http://domain.com/pressrelease/blah

i want to match `2,3` urls, urls have not contain of `index/(:num)` after `pressrelease`

i create this regular expression but it's does not working

```
(\/pressrelease\/)+((?!index).)*$
```

Comment: write regexp matching for only integer (\d) and/or string (\w) after the 'pressrelease' part ([\d\w]+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing the regex to `preg_match`, the below regex would be fine.

```
\/pressrelease\/(?!index\/\d+\b).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zY2sZ5/3)

`(?!index\/\d+\b)` negative lookahead assertion which asserts that the match `/pressrelease/` won't be followed by the string which is in the format like `index/number`.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works, but it doesn't match the first part of the URL.

```
^.*\/pressrelease\/(?!index).*$
```

Take a look at this demo on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/HRfLrR5ip6) to check it.